# How to create a set of Jenkins variables based on one chosen parameter?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using a jenkins freestyle project which has *parameterized build* enabled.

[image]

How can I create a set of variables based on the chose parameter?

For example:

When the parameter `param1` is chosen, I want the set of variables to be equal to

```
CONFIG=config_a.yml
AWS_PROFILE=aws-profile-aa
ANT_BUILD_FILE=buildA
```

When `param2` is chosen, the above set of variables should be set to

```
CONFIG=config_b.yml
AWS_PROFILE=aws-profile-bb
ANT_BUILD_FILE=buildB
```

`CONFIG`, `AWS_PROFILE`, and `ANT_BUILD_FILE` variables will be accessed in `Execute shell`, and `Invoke Ant`.

[image]

[image]

I don't want to define 3 parameters like this

[image]

Because my jenkins project should never build with `CONFIG`=`config_a.yml` and `AWS_PROFILE`=`aws-profile-bb` together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice) is able to solve my problem.

This plugin can create 4 parameters like this

[image]

Once `test_choice_parameter` is changed to `param2`, the other 3 parameters will change accordingly.

[image]

Here is my configuration of Active Choices:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why you not using ant? Its very easy to write build.xml file for ant

https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html