# Passing parameter value from properties file to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, properties, gradle.properties

I have problem with setting up my Jenkins.

What I want to achieve is when I click on "Build with Parameters" option and choose specific environment, one of parameters from .properties file should be passed into variableFromApp field.

I also want this field to be editable.

Can I do that?

[jenkins view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs9QY.jpg)

Comment: You can use `Active Choice Parameter` which support you write Groovy script, see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739610/how-to-create-a-set-of-jenkins-variables-based-on-one-chosen-parameter